# Post Production, How To Become Faster?

Tags: post-production, mastering, production-audio, audio-restoration, sound-effects-recording

So I have been doing audio post production and master for a friend of mine for a few months now. He is starting to have a higher demand for videos and is sending more to work on. They are commentaries about call of duty gameplay. I would like to know if there is software and or VSTs I could use to streamline the process.

Here are some examples of what I have done:

http://bit.ly/yungce0omc4

http://bit.ly/iwantrecon

I compose custom sound fx special events in the videos such as a double kill, and I add those in to the time points that they fit.

I level his selected music for the video in conjunction with his voice and the sound Fx.

I make skits, and music.

The biggest thing I do that takes the most time is fixing the shortcomings in his commentary. What is do for that is hand automate each second of it by use of a volume level. During the process I eliminate all shrill sounds ( he doesn't have a pop filter yet) from "S's" and "T's", lower his voice when he gets too loud, take out any plosives, take out long and loud Sizzles from "s", remove unneeded spit noises, lower Long breaths, rearrange some word when he says the wrong thing 2-4 times while trying to say the right thing, I add FX to his trademark saying at the end of the commentary.

I want to know of some of these procedures could be fixed simple with some types of EQ, I do use a pramstric EQ to help soften the "S's" and I get rid of most of the B plosives by taking out the range that his voice doesn't reach. It takes me about 3hrs to do this and make sure it's loudened, sound fx are playing at right times, levels are correct ( to my standards and his requests), and ultimately make sure he sounds really good.

The commentaries are usually 5-7 minutes with music and sound fx. I custom make the sound fx and sometimes the music too, as well as all audio mastering and mixing.

I am looking into get ozone 5 and isotope RX.

I am using:

FL Studio 10
FL fx and EQ (compressor, reverb 2, parametric EQ 2, multi-band compressor, FL volume (automation), and delay.
T-racks (mastering)
Waves platinum bundle (hiss removal and other)

He is currently recording with a blue snowball mic, so he sounds ALOT Better than when he first started and I have a bit less work to do than before..

Please let me know your opinions and the processes that you use for these procedures

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 5):

- Templates, templates, templates
- Know your hot keys front and back
- To do the above, practice, practice, practice so it becomes muscle memory
- As George said, organize your workflow into jobs, passes, or procedures - scattered workflow is the quickest way to get gummed up - in it's most simply form, do all editorial together as one, and do all mixing/processing together as another pass
- De-essing for the sibilance (try a HF rolloff of 7-10dB starting at about 7k)
- Compressor to help control the dialogue (within reason, you should be mixing into it not relying on it to force your levels) -set your dialogue to an average of about -18dB calibration, then load a compressor with something like 4:1-6:1 ratio, -8 threshold, 7ms Attack and 35ms Release

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot for you Answer, and a wonderful answer it is. I don't know if i stated this but i have been doing audio mixing and mastering for about 9+ yrs, so this is a niche for me. 

Prior to your answer i have had TONS of prcatice, just wanted to know what i could do to streamline the process. However these answers pretty much let me know that there isnt much. I do have templates for things, though most of the time i like to start fresh because it project is different from one another.

I have made a workflow for the post production i have been doing, I pretty much do the same things each ti

Comment: me now in a particular order. I JUST however figured out the correct way to use the R-Desser (as funny as that may seem). It knocked out all the major sibilance in an instance after i set the frequency to the right positions. So that alone save me A BUNCH of time than it takes me usually. I used to manually fix the sibilance by volume leveling . . .wow

i do already mix before i add compression and i have the rations set similar to yours.

Thank you so much for your advice it was helpful, i hope other learn from it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving your post workflow to a different DAW. I worked with FL Studio from versions 4 through 7, and when it came down to doing solid audio cutting/editing I could never find a good method because the interface targeted MIDI and sample management. I don't know what new features they've added since 7 though.

Have you heard of Reaper? It's free, and very robust. The paradigm is very much like Pro Tools in that the focus is on a Tracks window and a corresponding Mixer window (instead of the channels + patterns paradigm I remember from FL). I find that this is more suitable for post-production. FL Studio can be a solid music production tool in the right hands, but when it comes to editing audio in post I think its interface can slow you down.

http://www.reaper.fm/

Also, get Isotope RX2 because it really is as amazing as what they say.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, though i might strongly disagree in certain ways but i will try about reaper. I have used FL studio since 4 as well, and i am currently using FL 10. It is much much more versatile in all the areas that you mentioned. I honestly use it to record guitars, drums, editing, cutting samples, rearanging, and much more. I have NEVER had a problem with it in those areas, however i am looking for a VST that would cut some things out, and sometimes i just overly critical and obsessive ( a perfectionist).
Check this out, all recorded in FL studio:
bit.ly/koionair


Comment: http://bit.ly/koionair

Comment: The thing that i have noticed about a lot of people and FL studio, is that if you don't know how to use it people will say that its not possible to do a lot of things in it. Everyday i play my music for people and tell people that i use FL studio, people sand in awe and just don't believe me. 

It all comes down to this, you can pretty much do what you want to do in almost any DAW, as long as you know how to use it right and know all the tricks as well as have some up your sleeve. You have to make the DAW you use your own and know the ins and outs of it, from there you can do anything with it.

Comment: Well as I said, it can be a very powerful music creation tool in the right hands. I've just found it easier to use other DAWs when it comes to post production with video, which is what this particular project seems to be (the voice editing and all). You are right when you said you can do what you want to with any DAW, but different DAWs have different paradigms, so they're easier to use in different settings.

Comment: And to the song, solid percussion! And good mixing. I've seen FLStudio get knocked by users and non-users for not sounding good or being too quiet or flat, but that track's a good counter-argument. It's about how you use it. ~Cheers

Comment: Yep, FL studio has NEVER been too Quiet for me. hahah infact that is funny. I know i guy who uses it and has been doing music for Disney games, Soul Calibar V, and God Of War even. Check him out, he has demos on his website. http://zirconmusic.com/

His work is no where near quiet hahaha. He even has original mastered albums that are like a mix of electronic/orchestral/trance, and you know that is a style that is LOUD!

Check this song out that i produced and recorded, all in FL Studio. I didn't even master this one yet

bit.ly/koionair





Comment: @Ongaku - THE Zircon? If this is that lovable guy from OCRemix, then I've met him too. :P  I have Antigravity, and must to agree it's fat and full. :) Didn't one of his songs show up as the standard FL demo?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a lot easier if you split it into two jobs. First you should edit the voice recordings in a linear editing software, and when this is done you can add the music and sound effects by using a multichannel DAW.

For linear editing nothing beats Adobe Audition, with built in effects from iZotope. You can also use VST plugins with this. I use Waves plugins for de-essing, EQ, compression and filtering. And once the overall audio is filtered and enhanced, you can listen to it and edit out any shortcomings.

For step 2,  I would recommend Ableton Live. I've been using it for 5 years, and it never let me down. It also plays video, so you can sync the music and sfx in real time. It saves a lot of time and has a host of built in effects such as compressors, reverb, eq, delay etc.

This is how I usually approach this type of task. With Audition you can assign favorite effects to individual keys, so instead of navigating all the way to the compressor and setting all the parameters you can simply highlight a segment and press the specific key. This has streamlined my work greatly, and I don't want to kill myself each time I have to edit a 4 hour voice recording :)

Hope this helps,
G.

Comment: I didn't know that Audition has built in iZotope effects. Veddy nice.

Comment: Yeah they have. It's nothing like the RX series, but still a very good addition.

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer. FL Studio does everything that you just mentioned so i feel there is no need to switch in between that many DAWs. I do have a copy of ableton and i used to tinker with it, its a nice DAW. However i like the design and possibilities of FL studio a bit more. Though i see a lot of potential in Ableton, as for things i havent unlocked in it yet, and how fast you can get something going in it if you have the most expensive version.

I have used FL Studio for about 8+ yrs so i know it pretty much in and out. FL Studio does have linear editing in the playlist

Comment: FL Studio has multichannel editing as well as a piano roll, step sequencer, very large mixer, and much more. I absolutely love it, i use it for any type of editing. For some reason the video player in the one im using isn't working. So until i get that situated i am going to be using Reaper for that.

What i have been doing is saving a .wav of the video audio with cue markers attached to it, i put that back into FL studio and add the sound FX to the cues. Works perfect! as for editing, sibilance was the biggest issue and i figured out how to fix that within 1 minute everytime from now on!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Isotope RX2. They even uploaded a video on correcting mouth noise and plosives yesterday!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwdECSt3qX4&feature=g-like&context=G257a1bcALT2uPFgAAAA

Comment: Thank so much for you answer, i was looking at it already and i am definitely going to do that! Thanks again.